# IE11 unable to recognise viewport units in @media queries

Tags: css, media-queries, internet-explorer-11

Doing scaling code in css (as it doesn't rely on javascript being there), so the width / height ratio remains the same at all sizes. For all the currently supported browsers it works, but IE11 seems to totally ignore the media queries - has anyone come across a way to get it to work?

Using scss for ease of coding -

```
$width: 512;
$height: 350;

@mixin aspect-ratio() {
    $widthRatio: $width / $height;
    $heightRatio: $height / $width;

    $widthHeight: #{$widthRatio * 100}vh;
    $heightWidth: #{$heightRatio * 100}vw;

    /* Fix the width relative to the height */
    @media all and (min-width: $widthHeight) {
        max-width: $widthHeight;
    }

    /* Fix the height relative to the width */
    @media all and (min-height: $heightWidth) {
        max-height: $heightWidth;
    }
}

body {
    @include aspect-ratio();
}
```

Which outputs -

```
@media all and (min-width: 146.28571vh) {
    body {
        max-width: 146.28571vh;
    }
}
@media all and (min-height: 68.35938vw) {
    body {
        max-height: 68.35938vw;
    }
}
```

edit: As pointed out in a comment below I didn't need the media queries for this, however I still have two other things that do seem to need it - font scaling needs to be height based unless this puts blank space below the body when it needs to become width based, and there are "fake" footers which get `position:fixed` and a `top` added to them to keep them in the right place...

```
@mixin footer-aspect-ratio() {
    $footerHeightRatio: $height / $width;

    $footerHeightWidth: #{$footerHeightRatio * 100}vw;

    $footerHeightPx: #{$height}px;

    top: calc(100vh - 3rem);

    $footerTopMin: calc(#{$footerHeightWidth} - 3rem);

    /* Fix the height relative to the width */
    @media all and (min-height: $footerHeightWidth) {
        top: $footerTopMin;
    }

    /* Make sure the font can never get too short */
    @media all and (max-height: #{$height}px), all and (max-width: #{$width}px) {
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

and

```
@mixin font-scaling($font-vh: 4.5) {
    $widthRatio: $width / $height;
    $heightRatio: $height / $width;

    $widthHeight: #{$widthRatio * 100}vh;
    $heightWidth: #{$heightRatio * 100}vw;

    $fontsizeWidthHeight: #{$font-vh}vh;
    $fontsizeHeightWidth: calc(#{$heightRatio} * #{$font-vh}vw);
    $fontsizeMin: #{$font-vh * $height / 100}px;

    /* Fix the width relative to the height */
    font-size: $fontsizeWidthHeight;

    /* Fix the height relative to the width */
    @media all and (min-height: $heightWidth) {
        font-size: $fontsizeHeightWidth;
    }

    /* Make sure the font can never get too short */
    @media all and (max-height: #{$height}px), all and (max-width: #{$width}px) {
        font-size: $fontsizeMin;
    }
}
```

Comment: The good news is that you don't need the media queries. It works the same way in all browsers if you remove those. Just put the `body { ...` styles in the main style block.

Comment: Doh - while that is good news, the bad news is that I still need the same ability - for a nested position:fixed footer, and for the font scaling, which needs to take into account the width if it's got blank space at the bottom...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution is to not use min-width and min-height, but min-aspect-ratio and max-aspect ratio. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#aspect-ratio).

```css
html {background:white; height:100%}
body {background:yellow; height:calc(100% - 16px)}

@media all and (min-aspect-ratio: 512/350) {
    body {
        max-width: 146.28571vh;
    }
}
@media all and (max-aspect-ratio: 512/350) {
    body {
        max-height: 68.35938vw;
    }
}
```

```html
  This is a test. Again.
```

Which works in IE9 and up.

I'm not sure how the mixins in your question are supposed to work, but I hope this example will get you started.

Comment: That was it - somehow I'd completely missed the existence of these - the mixins were basically splitting the maths of what that does automatically :-)

Comment: nice one! although so annoying that vh not accepted by ie11 in @media! this solved it nicely

Comment: @HenryGibson Where does it say that? We are having the same problem and I haven't found much through Googling on the matter. Thanks

Comment: @HenryGibson `vh` and `vw` work fine in IE; it's `vmin` and `vmax` that have problems.

Comment: @ross_troha If you really have the same problem, then the same solution should work for you... I mean, I think it's best if you ask a new question.

Comment: @MrLister I meant the same problem where `max-height: 100vh` is not honored by IE in a media query